# First eigenvalue of the problem $-f^{\prime \prime} = \lambda f $ with $f(-1) = f(1) = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> Consider $f \in H^{2}(-1,1) \cap H_{0}^{1}(-1,1)$. The first eigenvalue of the problem
> $$
> -f^{\prime \prime} = \lambda f \ \ \text{with} \ \ f(-1) = f(1) = 0
> $$
> As it shows that the first eigenvalue is $\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}$ with eigenfunction $\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})$??

I know that ($\lambda > 0$)

If $F''(x)+\lambda F=0$, then
$$F(x)=c_1\cos \frac{\sqrt{\lambda}\pi}{2}x + c_2\sin \frac{\sqrt{\lambda}\pi}{2}x.$$
How $ 0= F(1) = F(-1) = c_2 \sin \frac{\sqrt{\lambda}\pi}{2}$. Soon $\lambda = 4n^{2}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $c_2 = 0 $.

And now? How to continue?

Comment: Characteristic equation is $m^2+\lambda=0$ and its roots are $\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}$ and not  $\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}/2$.

Comment: Why do you have  $\pi$ in the solution $F$ .? It should be $F(x)=c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x + c_2\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x.$

Comment: Plugging $\cos(\pi x/2)$ into both sides of the ODE yields 
$(\pi/2)^2\cos(-\pi/2) = \lambda \cos(-\pi/2)$, same for $x=1$, and on comparing coefficients $\lambda=\pi^2/4$, which may be multiplied by n for higher eigenvalues.

Comment: But, why eigenfunction $\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})$??

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't this function given? Luckily, it satifies both, ODE and BC, so only the first eigenvalue needs to be confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F''+\lambda F=0$$
For $\lambda > 0$:
$$\implies F(x)=c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x + c_2\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x.$$
Then apply initial conditions:
$$F(1)=c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda} +c_2\sin \sqrt{\lambda}=0$$
$$F(-1)=c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda} - c_2\sin \sqrt{\lambda}=0$$
Add both equations:
$$2c_1\cos \sqrt{\lambda}=0$$
$$\cos \sqrt{\lambda}=0$$
$$\sqrt {\lambda}=\dfrac {\pi}{2}+k\pi$$
First value of $\lambda$ is for $k=0$
$$ \implies \lambda =\dfrac {\pi^2}{4}$$
Now we have
$$F(1)=0 \implies c_2=0$$
$$F(x)=c_1 \cos \left( \dfrac {\pi}{2} x \right)$$

Comment: and eigenfunction $\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})$?

Comment: Yes because $F(1)=0 \implies c_2=0$ @user478963

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Yoy are welcome @user478963